# Is it possible to copy a file to the windows startup folder using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

and thanks for all your answers. But I'm very new to coding and try to teach it myself. So please be tolerant if it is a really stupid and easy question :c.

Basically I try to copy a file in the **Windows Startup Folder**. I did my research and it should be possible in the shutil module, or not? But i don't get the point.

Simon

(BTW I'm using Python 3.5)

Comment: A quick Google search should have told you that it is possible to copy files in Python. Did you have any particular reason to believe that the startup folder would be special?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `copyfile()` or `copy2()`. They are both in the `shutil` library.

More info: [copyfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile) and [copy2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy2)

Next time, do more research before asking.

Comment: I did my research! And the part with copy and the shutil module is not the problem. But How do i copy the file to the startup folder when there's no specific path. (the folder path changes with username)

Comment: I did my research! And the part with copy and the shutil module is not the problem. But How do i copy the file to the startup folder when there's no specific path. (the folder path changes with username) C:\Users\Main\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup here you can see my startup folder path for example. My windows account name is Main, (because it's my Main account). But with a different user the path changes with the different username. Is it possible to write code, that copies the file to the startup folder no matter what username is used? Sorry i ran out of time.

Comment: @Cxqe Use `os.getlogin()` to get the username. Then just join the first part of the string with the username and the second part of the string.